# Updating a View after an initial Render

Tags: javascript, react-native

Trying to wrap my head around how I could do this...

I have a view in React Native that I want to show/or hide based on some information from a server (using firebase.. not that it matters).
I can do this successfully just returning a value, but if I add a database call that determines to return it, it does not work.

The problem is the query returns fast, but might not return exactly when the view loads. Therefore I think by the time that If Loop in my code below finally runs, it is too late. **Is there a way once I have the information I need from the database whether or not to show the view, to ReRender the view, or reload it, so the view will show if the database returns true**

I should also add the thing I am querying the database with some information from this.props passed into the component

My current logic was (this might not be syntax, but I think you'll get the idea of the question):

```
returnOtherComponent(){

/*
This is just psuedo code, as the web query is a big block of text that is uneeded
*/
DatabaseIsTrue = Returned True from Web

if(DatabaseIsTrue){
   return (
      <View>
        <Text> HELLO! </Text>
      </View>
   );
}
}

render(){
  return(
    <View>
      {this.returnOtherComponent()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: So you want to render your view depending on the reponse of a fetch call? Is that the question? you could just render an activity-indicator until you have the response..

Comment: @dv3 yeah that pretty much is it..how do I that?

Comment: Mario is right - you should use a state variable for your data. When you update the state it'll trigger a rerender.. If you need further help let me know

Comment: okay awesome. Thank-you so much for your help.. one last question..if I am updating the state, i was under the impression it ran like a normal javascript object.. the reason i ask that is sometimes i want to add a component to it, but don't wanna use all the other parts of it.. like if this.state.array already exists, and I want to add this.state.array2, without losing this.state.array... Does that make sense? Didn't know if there was some clever way

Comment: as I understand it: this.setState({}) performs a shallow merge into a nextstate. this does not override old variables as you fear it. If you use replaceState this would be the case. -> https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use your *state* object to update the view.

So when the server request is back, you update the component *state* by *setState()* and the component will redraw.

```
returnOtherComponent() {
    if (this.state.DatabaseIsTrue) {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> HELLO! </Text>
            </View>
        );
    } else {
        return {}
    }
}

componentDidMount: function() {
    /*
      This is just psuedo code, as the web query is a big block of text that is uneeded
     */
     DatabaseIsTrue = Returned True from Web

    this.setState({
        DatabaseIsTrue: DatabaseIsTrue
    })
}

render(){
   return(
    <View>
      {this.returnOtherComponent()}
    </View>
   );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response mario! This is really helpful. One last question.. when I am doing this.setState({}), is there anyway i can set new parts of the state without rewriting the oldones, like lets say I have an array in there at this.state.array1, and I want to add a second array, but do not want to lose the first array..

Comment: When you set the new *state* you can just put the elements that are changed, no need to write all the state each time. the method *setState()* will update the current *state* by creating a new object that is a merge from the current state and your changes. This new object will became the *state*.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an ActivityIndicator before data is loaded.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    loading: true,
    listing: {},//this object contains list of data you are gonna load from server
  }

  this._decideContent = this._decideContent.bind(this);
}

_fetchFunction(){
  fetch(...)
  .then(...)
  .then(...)
  .then((response) => {
    this.state = {
      ...this.state,
      loading: false,//now that data is loaded, we don't need the spinner anymore
      listing: {data you fetched from server},
    }
  })
}

//if data is loaded, this function returns your component, if not, it returns an activity indicator
_decideContent(){
  let loading = this.state.loading;
  if(loading){
    this._fetchData();//call the function that fetches data
    return(
      <ActivityIndicator animating={loading} />
    )
  }
  else{
    return(
      <YourComponentContaingData listing = {this.state.listing} />
    )
  }
}

render(){
  return(
    {this._decideContent()}
  )
}
```